# Internet connection resets (wifi), no device has wifi for moment

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a few devices setup and I noticed this happens with both my old and new router (two different vendors&models)

This happens occasionally, and I tried wireshark today and this cought my attention:

```
No. Time            Source              Destination     Protocol Length Info
69  6.464423000     LiteonTe_7f:64:30   Broadcast       ARP 42  Who has 192.168.2.4?  Tell 0.0.0.0
73  7.451146000     LiteonTe_59:65:94   Arcadyan_e1:8c:cf   ARP 42  Who has 192.168.2.254?  Tell 192.168.2.1
85  9.450443000     LiteonTe_59:65:94   Arcadyan_e1:8c:cf   ARP 42  Who has 192.168.2.254?  Tell 192.168.2.1
91  10.521000000    LiteonTe_59:65:94   Broadcast       ARP 42  Who has 192.168.2.254?  Tell 192.168.2.1
93  10.860953000    LiteonTe_7f:64:30   Broadcast       ARP 42  Who has 192.168.2.254?  Tell 192.168.2.4
97  11.099463000    LiteonTe_7f:64:30   Broadcast       ARP 42  Who has 192.168.2.254?  Tell 192.168.2.4
```

where 192.168.2.254 is the gateway/router, 192.168.2.1 my laptop ip and 192.168.2.4 my sisters laptop.. what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its ARP traffic, it looks like 192.168.2.1 and 192.168.2.4 are looking for the gateway. You should see an ARP response to those queries that says what device has 192.168.2.254. Something like "ARP Reply 192.168.2.254 is at "

From a TCPdump:

```
14:10:26.907259 ARP, Request who-has 10.7.148.1 tell 10.7.149.249, length 46
14:10:27.043117 ARP, Reply 10.7.148.1 is-at 78:2b:cb:38:3e:49 (oui Unknown), length 46
```

The fact that you don't see a reply at all means that either the gateway is not responding as it should, or the request is not reaching the gateway.

Comment: ah so my wifi connection is just not strong enough! okay :) yeah i'm at the attic (2nd floor) and the router is at the other side on the base floor (0th). Thanks! Can accept in 6 minutes